# How can I duplicate a button inclusive its functions with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, button, duplicates, clonenode

I have a button which appends some elements. I want a button which duplicates this button.

I found some articles about `clone()`, but I believe that's jQuery?

I can't seem to find the answer but I thought something like this:

```
var copybutton = create("input");
    copybutton.type = "button";
    copybutton.id = "copybutton" + counter;
    copybutton.value = "copybutton";
    addEvent(copybutton, "click", duplicatefunction);

function duplicatefunction()
{
var duplicatebutton = appendbutton.cloneNode (true);
}
```

Well at least that would make sense to me a little, but of course it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: Cloning WITH event handlers will be quite a pain yourself, which is why people recommend you use a framework's clone method.  If you really want, you can copy their code.  However, keep in mind that jQuery's event system isn't trivial and probably won't correspond to your style of event registration.  Perhaps look at YUI or Prototype or other DOM frameworks for their clone methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
<div id="original">
   <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

You can use something like:

```
var e1 = document.getElementById("original"), e2;
e2 = e1.cloneNode(true);
```

Set the parameter to `cloneNode` true if you want to recursively copy the node and its children.

Comment: thank you so much! So i make the button in the body, but do i also use any further code for the button in javascript?

Comment: The question states "inclusive its functions", which I found to mean "in addition to cloning attached event handlers".  `cloneNode` does not clone them (afaik).

Comment: @strager is correct. You will need to copy event handlers by hand (`e2.onclick = e1.onclick; ...`), which makes the framework methods more attractive. If the event handler is declared in the HTML rather than attached dynamically, it will get copied by `cloneNode`.